# A lower bound on the sample space size given that there exist k-wise independent R.V

Tags: probability-theory

I was given the following homework question:

> Let $\Omega$ be a sample space s.t there exist $k$ wise independent
>   R.V $X_{1},\ldots X_{m}$ that distribute uniformly on
>   $\{1,\ldots,m\}$, what lower bound on $|\Omega|$ can you give ?

**My efforts:**

I can give a lower bound but I feel like it can be improved, since
I won't be using all of the data: I noted that 
$$
P(X_{1}=x_{1},\ldots X_{k}=x_{k})=\frac{1}{m^{k}}>0
$$
for all $\{x_{1},\ldots x_{k}\}\subseteq\{1,\ldots m\}$.

Thus, for every $\{x_{1},\ldots x_{k}\}\subseteq\{1,\ldots m\}$ there
exist $\omega\in\Omega$ s.t 
$$
X_{i}(\omega)=x_{i}
$$

for all $i$ 
and two different subsets of $\{1,\ldots m\}$ gives as different
$\omega$'s so I deduced 
$$
|\Omega|\geq m^{k}
$$

But I didn't use the fact that **all** subset of the $m$ R.V
are $k$ wise independent, just that there is **one** such subset,
which is weaker. Moreover, I used the fact that that the above probability
is just positive, and didn't use all the information I had which is
that the R.V distribute uniformly and that 
$$
P(X_{1}=x_{1},\ldots X_{k}=x_{k})=\frac{1}{m^{k}}
$$

Can I improve my bound ?

Comment: "Can I improve my bound ?" No, since $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_k)$ the identity map on $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}^k$ endowed with the uniform probability has the desired distribution.

Comment: @Did - Thank you for your comment. I have an issue with your example: for $m>k$ we need to have $m$ k-wise independent R.V, and not just $k$. in your example, can we define $m$ such variables on not just $k$ ?

Comment: Right, the minimal size $m^m$ is for $m$ independent random variables uniform on $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$. For $m$ $k$-wise independent random variables, the minimal size might be smaller -- although I do not see how at the moment.

Comment: Hi @Belgi, Interestingly enough, I'm also trying to understand how come due to simple counting considerations we get $|\Omega|\geqslant m^k$ and OTOH the bound is tight in the sense that we can actually construct such a sample space. What bugs me is that the calculation neglects the other $m-k+1$ r.v that also have to be $k$.w.i.